# Логгирование в разные файлы в Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Нужно вести логи приблизительно таким образом:

- Информационные сообщения сохраняются в одном файлу
- Сообщения об ошибках сохраняются в другом файле
- Может быть, каждый день логи нужно сохранять в новой директории, имя которой создается из текущей даты в текстовом формате

Как это можно сделать на спринге?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) отключаем встроенный логгер спринга

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

2) добавляем в зависимости какой хотим, к примеру Log4j

3) конфигурирем его как уже душе угодно

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn">

<Appenders>

    <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <ThresholdFilter level="INFO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5level %c{1} - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
    </Console>

    <RollingRandomAccessFile name="FILE" fileName="logs/system.log"
                             filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/system-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="50 MB"/>
        </Policies>
    </RollingRandomAccessFile>

    <RollingRandomAccessFile name="DEBUG" fileName="logs/system_debug.log"
                             filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/system_debug-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
        <MarkerFilter marker="DEBUG" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="50 MB"/>
        </Policies>
    </RollingRandomAccessFile>

</Appenders>

<Loggers>

    <Logger name="org.genfork" level="info" additivity="true">
        <AppenderRef ref="DEBUG"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="FILE"/>
    </Logger>
    <Logger name="com.owox.unione" level="info" additivity="true">]
        <AppenderRef ref="DEBUG"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="FILE"/>
    </Logger>
    <Logger name="org.springframework" level="info" additivity="true">
        <AppenderRef ref="DEBUG"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="FILE"/>
    </Logger>
    <Logger name="org.hibernate" level="info" additivity="true">
        <AppenderRef ref="DEBUG"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="FILE"/>
    </Logger>
    <Logger name="org.apache" level="info" additivity="true">
        <AppenderRef ref="DEBUG"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="FILE"/>
    </Logger>

    <Root level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </Root>

</Loggers>
```

Comment: А как настроить логгер, чтобы он записывал только информационные сообщения и не записывал сообщения об ошибках? Ведь приоритет сообщений об ошибках выше и они будут попадать в логгер информационных сообщений.

Comment: @typemoon Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.OFF); пробуйте, правда не уверен что поможет, так как не задавался этим вопросом

Comment: @GenCloud все тоже самое можно сделать, добавив конфиг logback.xml в класс паф.

Comment: @aleshka-batman , а это что не одно и тоже?

Comment: @GenCloud одно и тоже. Но убирать встроенный логгер спринга необязательно. Можно просто подкинуть свой logback.xml, и он заоверайдит стандартный спринг бутовский.

Comment: @aleshka-batman, это так с целью ненадобности лишних депов